# Using a shared enum across 15 nanoservices

Tags: java, architecture, object-oriented-design, microservices, kotlin

Originally posted here, moved to code review, redirected from code review back here as there is no code to review. I think the question is enough abstract to be asked here.

I have a mono repo with multiple nano services integrated with Kafka. The system data vesel is JsonMessage. There Are multiple formats Of json messages. These Json messages аre exchanged via these nano services. Same keys are used as element in constructing a key accessing data carried by these messages in a Redis cache. A global dictionary of property Keys is created via enum that is included as dependency to all systems:

```
enum Key {
  EVENT_NAME,
  COMMAND_NAME,
  CLIENT_ID
  TRANSACTION_ID,
  ORG_NUMBER,
  INCOME_DOCUMENT
...................
30+ more enrties
}
```

These keys fall in three categories, keys originating from the integration framework. Technical keys described in our application. And functional keys like organization number, income document and so on.

I attempted to split this enum into two enums, to isolate the DATA related keys in a separate enum. Using a marker interface would allow for two enums with Key abstraction.

```
enum SystemKey implements Key {
      CLIENT_ID, TRANSACTION_ID /* ... more keys */;
}



enum DataKey implements Key {
     ORG_NUMBER,INCOME_DOCUMENT /* ... more keys */;
}
```

This was blocked in a code review with the argument that

> "Key enum is describing all the Keys in the Kafka message, having two
> enums in place of one would diminish the value of having the enum
> Keys"

Each service is not interested in all Keys. What objective value is diminished by breaking this enum into two enums? For example:

- What can we not do with two enums that we can do with one?
- Or what code quality hazard do we create with two enums, but not with one?
- What about the opposite statements ? What are the advantages of each service exposing its own keys or splitting the keys by their responsibiliy?

Comment: Please do not [repost closed questions which you deleted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/445871/sharing-a-global-enum-accross-15-nano-services-independently-deployed).

Comment: maybe try compiling you example java?

Comment: also, whats with all this "can you elaborate?" reads like a homework question

Comment: @joshp Deleted questions are visible to users with 10k rep; the OP deleted the original after it was closed via community vote.

Comment: I was not able to uendelete it. Probably not enough reputation. I have 9K reputation on stackoverflow from answering questions. I am experienced developer and this is 100% not a homework question.

Comment: I am facing a very opinionated developer who wants to keep a single enum with as Of today 32 keys that will further expand as the product is in aktive development. I am trying to verify my sanity. How is global enum with 10s Of elements shared across 15 services a good idea ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov You hit the nail on the head, "opinionated". You and the other developer are both opinionated. For a question to work here it has to be reasonably grounded in the objective. I think there are reasonable objective questions lurking in your post, but they are kind of obscured by the presentation.

Comment: Any suggestions on particular points that can be more specific ?

Comment: Without further understanding of your domain, "*There Are multiple formats Of json messages.*" suggests to me that first and foremost, you should have a common key member that indicates the message format, then after that other data/metadata that helps qualify the content.

Comment: That we do have. The three general categories Of messages Event, Command and DATA. All Of these when translated to json contain system data and may contain also some functional data

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. Looks very good. My long term goal was to vcreate even more enums since not all services Are interested in all data and i wanted to reduce the knowledge and the dependencies in between these services.  Another goal was to use this enum in order to perform lookup on the data with functional meaning from the json message but also from the Redis cache.

Answer (score 4):

If the single big enum is used as a key value in a single message property to allow readers to determine the expected message format and content, then there are some consequences to breaking it into two enums. For example...

1. A single enum **enforces uniqueness** of key names **in source code** across all record types. Two enums can have key names that duplicate each other, and require monitoring or naming conventions to avoid duplicates. Are key names used in the json messages?
2. **Ordinal values** of the two enums **will overlap** unless they are explicitly defined. If you ever use the ordinal values in a setting where you don't know which enum to reference, this is a problem.
3. If you want to build a dictionary of all keys and their values a single enum allows you to easily do it with and array indexed by ordinal value or an EnumMap, which is an efficient structure for small, stable key domains. EnumMap implementations typically store values in an array indexed by ordinal value [Reference: OpenJDK 8 Source](https://github.com/keerath/openjdk-8-source/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/EnumMap.java), but you use it like a map in your code.
4. If you have two enums and want to use both enums as keys for a single dictionary using an EnumMap, first you will hit warnings that you are mixing generic types when you try to `put()` values. If you get around those, easy enough to do, you will have keys from one enum that overwrite keys from the other, unless you explicitly put their ordinal values in different ranges.

EnumMap is a Java specific implementation detail, but it serves to demonstrate a general disadvantage in the inability to rely on ordinal values. If you use a structure keyed by String then the overlapping ordinals are not important, but the uniqueness of string names remains important.

**Those Are Some Concrete Disadvantages - Can they be avoided?**

Yes, but not for free.

If your team never uses ordinal values, or only uses them in places where the two enum types are separated, you can ignore overlapping ordinal values.

If you change the message structure to have two message keys, say an Event Type and a Message Type, and then make all the code that serializes, deserializes, evaluates, creates these messages understand which Message Type belongs with which Event Type, then you can still have uniqueness and the ability to use ordinal values for each Type.

But you have a more complex structure and set of rules to follow. If messages currently have just one key governed by one Enum type, it could be quite a bit of work to revise the code and test it all.

You would need a good justification or reward for it.

It could be a better design overall. That depends on your project's requirements. But it might not be worth switching late in the game.

**Advice**

Try to find objective advantages to the approach you prefer. Are they worth the cost? You're not crazy to look at a big enum and wonder if it's a maintenance problem. The answer to that depends on details of your project and team. To my eye, 30 to 60 values does not instantly seem like a problem. Having more enums representing more key domains could be more complex.

Comment: In project there is no iteration upon these keys unless there is some form of frontend validation and in general when a lookup is perform the party peforming the lookup is interested in a specific value. The combination of Event /Command/Data plus potentialy transaction ID identifies uniquely a particular message. Probably transaction ID even without the other two identify it , but with the other two you become aware of the precise context and data that it contains.

I am not sure that in our case we have any real iteration. Except when validating and then it is on a limited set of values.

Comment: Yes, the KEY names are used in the json messages. This is how the lookup is performed.

Comment: I mean it is enum with string value and the string value matches the property in the json message.

Comment: Sure. You know your project. Your team may not care about ordinal values. I sometimes care. Most teams I worked with would mainly care about the string uniqueness, and complexity, which can be a mater of opinion. There are lots of ok ways to do this.

Comment: I think creating a dictionary named f.ex. Names does not exclude having 2 enums one named SystemKeys the other named DataKeys. These enums can refer to the dictionary enum when initializing their values? So I kind of don't see how having a dictionary excludes the creation of additional enums based on the property values. And if we are to iterate upon all keys we can use an interface ?

Comment: This is under the presumption we dont use enumMap and dont mix the values in it.

Comment: As a semi-related side note, sealed enums solve all of these problems you have, while still allowing you to separate your enums out as you wish. The Java Team (the Amber Dev Team) have decided not to do that because they felt it didn't justify the effort at the moment.